# How to read music only specific folder in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello friends I am creating project which have lots of sound but problem is that I don't want make its online because I want user can read this sound offline it learning app now I want first I store my all music in any cloud platform when user open app it download song from cloud and make external folder in mobile phone and music read my app only on that specific folder which is created in mobile phone second this music not shown in mobile default MP3 player its can be only read in my app it possible or not?

Comment: hey bro, have your work done? I also want such type of functionality in my app, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible by using [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) and accessing the document directory.

[According to official documentation:](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files#1-find-the-correct-local-path)

> Documents directory is directory for the app to store files that only it can access. The system clears the directory only when the app is deleted. On iOS, this corresponds to the NSDocumentDirectory. On Android, this is the AppData directory.

You can follow the link of the documentation I gave you to find a detailed example. Otherwise here is the idea:

```
Future<String> get _localPath async {
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

  return directory.path;
}

Future<File> get _localFile async {
  final path = await _localPath;
  return File('$path/counter.txt');
}

Future<File> writeMusique(Music music) async {
  final file = await _localFile;

  // Write the file.
  return file.writeAsBytes(music.asBytes());
}
```

I wrote the music as Bytes using an imaginary `Music` class, but you should adapt this according to the class representing your music.